# Unable to resolve module `../../screens/AuthScreen` from `src\screens\Welcome\Welcome.js`

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, mobile-application

I'm new at react-native and try to build an app. When I run my code I'm getting this error:
[image]

As you can see the path, my code is correct. I don't understand why I'm getting this error, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import AuthScreen from '../AuthScreen/AuthScreen';
```